# Is it possible to make an android launcher using flutter with widgets support?

Tags: android, flutter, android-launcher

I want to create a custom home launcher for android. I'm wondering if I could do that with flutter. Are there any support regarding that? (Complete with wallpaper, widget, etc.)

Comment: This question is general and not specific. The questioner does not even try his project.

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course you can make it with flutter.

You need to edit `AndroidManifest.xml` file under `<intent-filter>` section :

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

that to ask the end user to use your Launcher always or just once. It is that easy !

See this link [Custome Android Launcher](https://dev.to/mh_shifat/make-your-own-custom-android-launcher-using-flutter-558j) for more information.